# Python3 OpenCV Convert Raw YUYV422 from WebCam to RGB

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, v4l2

I am trying to convert a RAW YUYY422 Frame of size 640x480 to RGB in Python3 OpenCV.
I've looked in the OpenCV Docs and google various solution, but cannot seem to get it to work.

The error I keep getting is a variant of:

```
Before 614400 <class 'bytes'>
After 614400 <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
(614400,)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "./capture.py", line 111, in <module>
cv2.cvtColor(dataBuffer, dataBuffer, cv2.COLOR_YUV2RGB_UYVY);
TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

Here is the code that I am trying to convert with:

```
    buf = v4l2_buffer()
    buf.type = V4L2_BUF_TYPE_VIDEO_CAPTURE
    buf.memory = V4L2_MEMORY_MMAP
    fcntl.ioctl(vd, VIDIOC_DQBUF, buf)  # get image from the driver queue
    mm = buffers[buf.index]

    dataBuffer = mm.read()
    print("Before",len(dataBuffer),type(dataBuffer))
    dataBuffer = np.fromstring(dataBuffer, np.uint8)
    print("After",len(dataBuffer),type(dataBuffer))
    #dataBuffer = dataBuffer.reshape( 640, 480 )
    print(dataBuffer.shape)

    cv2.cvtColor(dataBuffer, dataBuffer, cv2.COLOR_YUV2RGB_UYVY);

    dbusClient.run(dataBuffer)
    mm.seek(0)
    fcntl.ioctl(vd, VIDIOC_QBUF, buf)  # requeue the buffer
```

How can I accomplish this conversion?

UPDATE: Per comment:

```
    for _ in range(50):  # capture 50 frames
    buf = v4l2_buffer()
    buf.type = V4L2_BUF_TYPE_VIDEO_CAPTURE
    buf.memory = V4L2_MEMORY_MMAP
    fcntl.ioctl(vd, VIDIOC_DQBUF, buf)  # get image from the driver queue
    mm = buffers[buf.index]

    dataBuffer = mm.read()
    dataBuffer = np.fromstring(dataBuffer, dtype=np.uint8)
    dataBuffer2 = cv2.cvtColor(dataBuffer, cv2.COLOR_BGR2YUV)

    dbusClient.run(dataBuffer)
    mm.seek(0)
    fcntl.ioctl(vd, VIDIOC_QBUF, buf)  # requeue the buffer
```

Gives Error:

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (scn == 3 || scn == 4) in cvtColor, file /io/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/color.cpp, line 11144
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "./capture.py", line 106, in <module>
dataBuffer2 = cv2.cvtColor(dataBuffer, cv2.COLOR_BGR2YUV)
cv2.error: /io/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/color.cpp:11144: error: (-215) scn == 3 || scn == 4 in function cvtColor
```

Comment: use `img_out = cv2.cvtColor(img_in, cv2.COLOR_BGR2YUV)`

Comment: thanks - I tried that but I get the new error I detailed in my post. Also, shouldn't it be YUV2RGB?

Comment: Maybe you could identify your camera since your title and description disagree about the actual format...

Comment: Actually it should be with the flag `COLOR_YUV2RGB_Y422 ` since you want from an specific type of YUV... and you are passing from YUV to RGB